# Could not load JDBC driver class [org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver] in spring with hive

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc

i try to connect hive through my spring application.I have configured hive with MYSQL server.I have used below properties for database configuration.

```
db.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
db.driver=org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver
db.url=jdbc:hive2://localhost:10000/MY_DATABASE
db.class=org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver
db.user=hadoop
db.password=hadoop
```

this is what i have used in db.properties file.But when running the application i got below exception.

```
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:353)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:153)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
```

In pom.xml i have added below dependency

```
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
              <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
              <version>2.1.1</version>
            </dependency>
```

Comment: Read the stacktrace again. It complains of `Property 'driverClassName' threw exception;` I cannot see this property?

Comment: i have kept this property in db.properties file

Comment: it is taking this property value only db.class=org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong driver class name and hence the error. You need to replace this

```
db.driver=org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver
```

with

```
db.driver=org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver
```

You can refer to the driver documentation [here](https://hive.apache.org/javadocs/r0.11.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/hive/jdbc/HiveDriver.html), just in case you need that.

Hope this should resolve your problem!

Comment: i have tried and got the below error Could not load JDBC driver class [org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver] and for your information i have created a java program using this org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver driver class name and that is working fine.But when i tries with my web application i got the exception as stated upper.For both cases i have added dependency of  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
     <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
     <version>2.1.1</version>
      </dependency>

Comment: You said that you are having issues with a web application right, then the driver jar should be part of your WEB-INF/lib folder.

Comment: yes i have added that dependency please check my post i have updated

Comment: Can you check whether the jar is available under WEB-INF/lib folder?